# Spatialite Spatial Views doesn't display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sql-view, dbmanager

I have views stored in a spatialite database accessed via QGIS. The views were created by another person on a different computer. The geometry column is well registered in the table views_geometry_columns but when  I add the view to the canvas with DB Manager It's seems to just be an attribute table without geometry. 
I've tried the classical SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics('view_name') but it doesn't change anything.

Any solution(s) ?

Comment: Is there a unique ID column? I have had a similar problem using PostgreSQL (with QGIS and ArcMap). I needed to add an ID column casted to integer. With PostgreSQL, it looked like that: (ROW_NUMBER() OVER())::integer AS id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and wrote out steps on how to load it properly using DB Manager here. [Spatialite view appears 'filtered' in attribute table, won't load in canvas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254713/spatialite-view-appears-filtered-in-attribute-table-wont-load-in-canvas/268884#268884) Give that a go?

As @Gob Tron mentioned you need the view to have a unique ID column and this has to be specified. And the geometry mysteriously does turn up empty in QGIS 2.18.x but it's still there.