# Geometry loss/mix up of SpatiaLite view joining two tables

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatialite, sql-view, spatialite-gui

I have two SpatiaLite tables:

- Sites (with geometry column) (ca. 5000 single sites)
- Samples (ca. 6800 samples)
  To display the samples in QGIS I want to create a spatial view showing all samples at their respective locations from sites joined using the attribute field *ID_site*, however, the geometry is not joined (correctly) for all samples.

a) **View Composer of spatialite_gui** joins the tables *using 'ID Site'* and using rowid as the views_geometry_column - but always shows a "filtered view" displaying only the sites.
QGIS shows a "filtered view" restricted to the number of sites. All locations with more than one sample can not be accessed in QGIS via *"Zoom to Feature/Flash Feature"*. Following the advice of [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254713/spatialite-view-appears-filtered-in-attribute-table-wont-load-in-canvas>](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254713/spatialite-view-appears-filtered-in-attribute-table-wont-load-in-canvas%3E) *Update SQL layer in QGIS* with other unique(!) fields for all samples (e.g. id_sample or rowid from the sample table) do not change the result.

[image]

[image]

Variation of the join (*FROM samples JOIN sites ON ...* to *FROM sites JOIN samples ON ...*), variation the type of join (join, left join) as well as reassigning the id in QGIS via *Right click* layer *Update SQL Layer* do not result in the correct display of all samples.

**b) by hand**
Creating the View via SQLite and registering the view by hand (id_samples correctly registered in the view_geometry_columns table and updated via *"Update SQL Layer"* in QGIS as suggested here
[Spatialite view appears 'filtered' in attribute table, won't load in canvas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254713/spatialite-view-appears-filtered-in-attribute-table-wont-load-in-canvas)
) shows all 6800 samples in QGIS, however, their location is mixed up as the following images of a rectangular selection ares shows

```
CREATE VIEW view_join AS
    SELECT spls.ID_site,
           spls.ID_sample,
           sites.ID_site,
           sites.site_nom,
           sites.geometry
      FROM Samples AS spls
           JOIN
           Sites AS sites ON (spls.id_site=sites.id_site);
INSERT INTO views_geometry_columns (view_name, view_geometry, view_rowid,f_table_name,f_geometry_column,read_only)
VALUES ('view_join', 'geometry','id_sample','sites','geometry',0);
```

[image]

I am sure I am not the first one to join many samples to a few sites thus this complex problem for a standard routine took me by surprise or else I am missing something quite simple.
The problem is probably related to the joining or the adressing of the geometry column but having been through all variations I am at a loss.

Comment: with the SQL query you pasted in your question, could it be that your ID column is `id_sample` but you have registered `id_samples` (with an extra s) as the rowid?

Comment: Well spotted (probably a me editing myself error) but no that is not the reason. I checked and the tables & views are correct. Thanks.