# Create view and display in QGIS of a spatial table in geopackage or SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, geopackage, sql-view

I need to create 4 views of a spatial table in a geopackage or SpatiaLite (no preference at the moment). I tried with geopackage, but the view is displayed as a datatable and not displayed as a layer in QGIS.

The code I used was:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT * 
FROM spatial_table
WHERE attribute LIKE 'Something%'
```

Are there additional references to add to the geopackage? The documentation could not help me get through it : https://www.geopackage.org/guidance/modeling.html

I did not try with SpatiaLite.

Comment: I think you can't use " SELECT * " but that you need to list all the field in order to QGIS to detect the geometry column...

Comment: You got already an answer about how to add the required metadata into GeoPackage. This (perhaps partly outdated) document explains what must be done for the metadata with SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/Using-Views-Basic.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Create a only a view doesn't enought to QGIS Geopackage. [Read this Issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18026)

```
- add the view name to the table `gpkg_contents`
AFTER that
- add the geometry column to the table `gpkg_geometry_columns`
```

So in your case:

```
INSERT INTO `gpkg_contents`(`table_name`,`data_type`,`identifier`,`min_x`,`min_y`,`max_x`,`max_y`,`srs_id`)
VALUES ('strom_zasah','features','strom_zasah',-549173.0,-1185720.0,-548426.0,-1185130.0,5514);

INSERT INTO `gpkg_geometry_columns`(`table_name`,`column_name`,`geometry_type_name`,`srs_id`,`z`,`m`)
VALUES ('strom_zasah','geom','Point',5514,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A successful way I use:

1. Load `gpkg` in DB Manager with `SpatiaLite` tool
2. Create a view with an [unique id and a geometry column](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254713/spatialite-view-appears-filtered-in-attribute-table-wont-load-in-canvas/268884#268884)
3. Add view name and details in table `gpkg_contents` with an `INSERT`
4. Add geometry column and details in table `gpkg_geometry_columns` with an `INSERT`
5. Diconnect `gpkg` and close `QGIS`
6. Open `QGIS` again and load `gpkg` with `GeoPackage` tool. Layer is now visible as a geometric layer and can be loaded.